# Should I use TempData or RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a delete action on my Controller. It has a check to see whether the user is actually allowed to delete.

My question is, if they are not allowed to delete:

Should I redirect back to my Index action (that lists all the files that they can delete) and pass it an error message in TempData saying "You are not allowed to delete this resource".

OR

Should I select all the files that they can delete, list them and show the error all within the delete action?

What is the best practice?

Note: I'm not concerned about Authorization/Authentication.

Comment: Maybe just don't let them click delete on items they're not allowed to, and you won't have to deal with this scenario at all? I realize this isn't always convenient...

Comment: what you are using as primary key -> Integer or GUID ?

Comment: Are you checking each item for permission to delete, or are you checking that the user can perform deletes in general?

Comment: Im checking for some arbitrary condition, unrelated to the user permissions performing the action. I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the delete action is hit via HTTP post, [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is generally the best practice here in order to prevent a double post, so I'd opt for redirecting with temp data. Double-posting may not be dangerous in this particular case, but all else being equal, opt for consistency.

Comment: From what I've read - people seem to agree that its not good to PGR if you are not updating data on the server.

Comment: I don't know that I would agree. In terms of correctness I don't think it matters much. In ASP.NET MVC, copying ModelState to TempData and redirecting is a very common pattern. There are even solutions for [making that happen automatically](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc).

Comment: Yea - I'm also not sold on whether I agree to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Post/Redirect/Get, here is the filter attribute for this (don't remember actually where I found that):

```
/// <summary>
/// When a RedirectToRouteResult is returned from an action, anything in the ViewData.ModelState dictionary will be copied into TempData.
/// When a ViewResultBase is returned from an action, any ModelState entries that were previously copied to TempData will be copied back to the ModelState dictionary.
/// </summary>
public class ModelStateToTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public const string TempDataKey = "__MvcContrib_ValidationFailures__";

    /// <summary>
    /// When a RedirectToRouteResult is returned from an action, anything in the ViewData.ModelState dictionary will be copied into TempData.
    /// When a ViewResultBase is returned from an action, any ModelState entries that were previously copied to TempData will be copied back to the ModelState dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

        var controller = filterContext.Controller;

        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)
        {
            //If there are failures in tempdata, copy them to the modelstate
            CopyTempDataToModelState(controller.ViewData.ModelState, controller.TempData);
            return;
        }

        //If we're redirecting and there are errors, put them in tempdata instead (so they can later be copied back to modelstate)
        if ((filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult || filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) && !modelState.IsValid)
        {
            CopyModelStateToTempData(controller.ViewData.ModelState, controller.TempData);
        }
    }

    private void CopyTempDataToModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        if (!tempData.ContainsKey(TempDataKey)) return;

        var fromTempData = tempData[TempDataKey] as ModelStateDictionary;
        if (fromTempData == null) return;

        foreach (var pair in fromTempData)
        {
            if (modelState.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
            {
                modelState[pair.Key].Value = pair.Value.Value;

                foreach (var error in pair.Value.Errors)
                {
                    modelState[pair.Key].Errors.Add(error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                modelState.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CopyModelStateToTempData(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        tempData[TempDataKey] = modelState;
    }
}
```

All you need to do is to mark you actions with "ModelStateToTempData" (in two actions: market with HttpGet and HttpPost). Like this (code from my project):

```
    [ModelStateToTempData]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View("AlreadyLoggedIn");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ModelStateToTempData]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // other logic here
        }
        return RedirectToRoute("Login");
    }
```

Route config (just in case):

```
    routes.MapRoute("Login", "login", new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" });
```